# Django API returns 404 error but only 30% of the time. How to identify error in Docker setup?

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu, nginx, wagtail

I have a script that hits a simple API on all my servers every hour to ensure they are functioning properly. My newest server isn't using my normal stack, so I suspect I've configured it improperly. It is currently returning occasional 404 errors to the logging script.

**Server Config**

- Ubuntu, Nginx, PostgreSQL, Supervisor;
- Running a Docker container with Django/Wagtail and Gunicorn.

Looks fine when I visit in webbrowser, but my script logged four 404s in the last 12 hours.

My supervisor log shows the 404s but doesn't provide any additional useful information:

```
[2018-07-16 20:22:35 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2018-07-16 20:22:35 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2018-07-16 20:22:35 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
Not Found: /_server_health/
Not Found: /_server_health/
Not Found: /_server_health/
```

There is no relevant information captured in the Nginx log.

Can anyone recommend any steps I can take to gather further information? Or does this fit the pattern of any known problematic server configs?

---

**Edit**: It looks like Wagtail is sometimes causing the 404: "Raised by:   wagtail.core.views.serve"

Maybe a problem in my urls.py? Should this be configured differently for Wagtail?

`url(r'^_server_health$', status_api),`

Comment: Is it possible that those 404s are caused by the webserver not being operational yet? The log shows that the worker is booting, but it can take some time before it is operational

Comment: Good question! Nginx was started at the beginning of the 12-hour period, so I would think it should have been operational the entire time. Perhaps the Docker container had a slight delay due to dormancy which caused Nginx to return a 404?